# Linq sorting on the basis of indexed element

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to sort a query on the basis of array index. See the code below -

```
query = data.Users;
query = query.Where(u=>u.IsActive);
query = query.OrderBy(u=>u.LName);
query = query.OrderBy(u=>u.Phone[0]);
```

everything is working fine except last line. It is showing following error -

```
NotSupportedException was unhandled.
The expression [10007].Phone.get_Item(0) is not supported.
```

**Edit**

I have tried -

```
query = query.OrderBy(u=>u.Phone.First());
query = query.OrderBy(u=>u.Phone.FirstOrDefault());
```

Phone is a string array.

Comment: Are you looking for query = query.OrderBy(u=>u.Phone); ?

Comment: Due you want to sort on the basis of LName and Phone

Comment: @Praveen: No. The Phone has a lot of elements. I just want it to be sorted on the basis of first Phone value i.e. Phone[0].

Comment: @user2484943 : what is phone type ? What is phone[0] type ?

Comment: @Satpal: Phone is a string array. I want it after the sorting of LName, but you can neglect it at this point.

Comment: could you edit your question to post how to define `User` class?

Comment: Can anyone let me know why I got negative vote?

Comment: Incomplete and ambiguous question, bad use of LINQ, and it wasn't my downvote. Linq to Objects? Linq to NHibernate? Linq to EF? Linq to SQL? LINQ tries to convert your lambdas to your provider's language. If it can't it will warn you about it. 
Besides, LINQ doesn't replace knowledge of SQL, if that's what you have underneath. Are you trying to sort a table of users, by joining it to their phones and picking an arbitrary phone entry to do it? Because that's what your code says

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use ThenBy instead of the second orderby:

```
query = data.Users;
query = query.Where(u=>u.IsActive);
query = query.OrderBy(u=>u.LName);
query = query.ThenBy(u=>u.Phone[0]);
```

Otherwise you will just reorder the whole array, instead of ordering by the 2 fields you want.

Comment: @user2484943 the answer from peer will not solve your problem, but its definitly worth mentioning it. If you use `OrderBy` multiple times only the last one will win. If you want to sort by more than one value you will need `ThenBy`